# Automatic publish of sql server project after each build on VS2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I am using visual studio 2015 and have a SQLServer project, what I want is that whenever i build the project it automatically gets published to sql server. In TFS we can achieve it by following
Update Build definition -> Process -> MSBuild arguments -> /t: Build /t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath = filePath.publish.xml
On local pc we can use the following command to achieve the task
msbuild ProjectName.sqlproj /t:build  /t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=filePath.publish.xml

But how can we update the build definition of the project so that when I build it on my local machine it gets published automatically without using command line

Answer (score 0):

> how can we update the build definition of the project so that when I build it on my local machine it gets published automatically without using command line

To accomplish this, unload your project, edit the project file ProjectName.sqlproj. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag `</Project>`, place below scripts:

```
<Target Name="DeployDB" AfterTargets="build">
  <Message Importance="high" Text="************** Star Deploying DB **************"/>
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Deploying Project: $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)$(MSBuildProjectName).sqlproj" />
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Deployment Profile: $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)PublishProfiles$(MSBuildProjectName).publish.xml" />

  <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)$(MSBuildProjectName).sqlproj” Properties=”SqlPublishProfilePath=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)PublishProfiles$(MSBuildProjectName).publish.xml" Targets="sqlPublish" />
</Target>
```

You can use some of [MSBuild Reserved and Well-Known Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx) like $(MSBuildProjectName) and $(MSBuildProjectDirectory), for complete list

BTW, automatic publish will slow you down, and you probably don't need to publish for every build. Under this condition, you can add a `Condition` for this target so that you select whether you need to automatic publish of sql server project after each build(Do not forget to add a Configuration with `LocalAutoDeploy`).

```
<Target Name="DeployDB" AfterTargets="build" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'LocalAutoDeploy'">
```